# Windows 7 On Screen Keyboard - Prevent from ever opening

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have an application on my computer which pops up the on screen keyboard any time that an input field is clicked (for text entry). This application was designed for windows 8 touch screen machines without a keyboard (tablets), but I am running 7 and would like to never see the on screen keyboard.

I've tried `"Control Panel" -> "Tablet PC Settings" -> "Other" -> "Input Panel Settings" -> "Opening".`

and disabling it there, but no luck.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try two options to ensure the on screen keyboard does not appears.

Option 1:

Try disabling the On Screen keyboard. osk.exe is the executable for the On screen keyboard. So try disabling it from the Startup. So that it does not starts automatically in future:

1. Go to Start type “msconfig” without the quotes and press Enter.
2. Go to “Startup” tab.
3. Look for any entry which appears to run osk.exe.
4. If there is any entry, uncheck the entry and then press Apply.

Option 2:

Delete the Registry entry of the On Screen Keyboard executable:

1. Go to Start, type regedit and press Enter.
2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Accessibility
      On right side of of screen
           right-click on "Configuration"
           select modify
           if Value Data contains "osk", delete that text

Hope this helps.

Comment: the registry one is a neat trick. I forgot there is another thing I can do; under Windows Features uninstalling the Tablet PC feature.